# Elasticsearch: Block index from search

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there any options in elasticsearch to block index from search?

```
Ex: i have 5 index and i block 4th index from search and elasticsearch search only from 1, 2, 3 and 5 index.
```

is it possible to block index from search in elasticsearch?

Comment: You could also try index alias that would contain only 4 indexes you want to query. If you want more flexibility you could address indexes directly like /index1,index2,index3,index5. More info [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/multi-index.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is dynamically update-able setting called `index.blocks.read` that you can set for those specific indices. From the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/index-modules.html#dynamic-index-settings):

> `index.blocks.read`
>
> Set to `true` to disable read operations against the index.

Comment: and if later on i want to unblock that index what should i do?

Comment: You set the setting back to `false`.

Comment: if i set index.blocks.read to true then after any new doc can be add in that index means only search will block?

Comment: Yes. I suggest testing this with a test index and see how it behaves.

Comment: Thanks Andrei Stefan

Comment: when i was set index.blocks.read to true and then perform search query it's give me exception 

{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"cluster_block_exception","reason":"blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/7/index read (api)];"}],"type":"cluster_block_exception","reason":"blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/7/index read (api)];"},"status":403}

Comment: Right. And what's the problem with that?

Comment: What do you mean? That's the expected behavior. Reads are blocked for that index.

Comment: is there any way to filter index in search query that are block?

Comment: Can you try adding `ignore_unavailable=true` as a parameter to your search request?

Comment: Can't think of another way of ignoring that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't now a default built-in way but there is a security plugin that can do that in an easy way: https://github.com/sscarduzio/elasticsearch-readonlyrest-plugin